# Themes, blocks, and content ... Oh my!

Tags: blocks

I am a newbie to Drupal/Acquia Dev Desktop. Please excuse me if this is a dumb question.

I'm trying to grasp the relationship between themes (the one I chose is Corked Screwer), blocks, and content. In Corked Screwer there are images on the top half of the page/node and my content is at the bottom.

Am I understanding correctly that Content/main page content is where my typed-in content is displayed? I can control this with Visibility Settings/Content Types, etc. Yes?

How do I go about customizing the top half of the page to replace the default images with my own? Can you point me to a good video tutorial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Corked Screwer" is a theme, and slideshow is created by Views Block. You should able to change the image by modify that slideshow page, because each slide is created by a slideshow node.

Comment: OK. I found an image labeled slider-img1.png in C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\drupal-7.36\sites\all\themes\corkedscrewer\images\local. I replaced it with one of my images. It worked. I then found https://www.drupal.org/node/1907040 that pointed me to page.tpl.php. I'll check into it tomorrow. I also found some videos that are helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0i5P3QGm5s &  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYSSM3pNBTI. I've not yet watched the second one. Have to sign off until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the **Main page content** block is where your content will render. Yes those visibility settings control on what page/content type/role will show that block content area. Typically, you want to leave this block alone since it's the main presentation of your content (what's the point of having a page if it doesn't have any content?).

It looks like the CorkedScrewer's default home page is more a demo template to demonstrate its block regions; you can't replace the images without overwriting the existing ones in its **images** folder.  It can vary based on the theme developer, but usually you can control a theme's slideshow images from its settings page in **/admin/appearance**.

Comment: The second video was not very helpful. It talked about using Firebug. Firebug may be somewhat useful. There are settings for slideshow at admin/appearance, but none for the images presented. The Views module is not installed so I cannot click Views/Block. I did find all this in page.tpl.php. Perhaps the best way I can fool around with this theme is to make a sub-theme. The first video (above) helped me do that. I copied page.tpl.php into it and made changes, but they don't seem to work as I expect. Is there a better video or tutorial you can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Now that I've learned a bit more about Drupal and got into the inside of Open Outreach I decided to use the Open Outreach theme and have learned how it works. The Open Outreach them uses Panels & Mini Panels. I don't know much about them, but I learned from http://openoutreach.org/section/blocks is that this theme uses the Context UI module. I followed the instructions to customize my home page.